# Trying adjust displayed info on OpenSea of Solana NFT collection

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, opensea, candy-machine

I created a Solana NFT collection using Candy Machine v2 (CM) and OpenSea automatically found and displayed the collection. Their documentation states that one should be able to adjust the info displayed about the collection on OpenSea when connecting a creator wallet to OpenSea. However, I don't see the collection when I connect the creator wallet.

This is the CM:
https://www.solaneyes.com/address/B5HzhwdBCUL2jboP2Q4bdeRozBe6XJj7AkNFNNpyyMyF?cluster=mainnet

When I created the CM I used a Solana CLI wallet to hold the update authority and I don't want to import this wallet into a web wallet as I then loose the ability to update the CM via sugar and my CLI wallet. However, it seems that many Solana projects were able to edit their info displayed on OpenSea so I must be missing something simple. Does anyone have experience?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As this [official page of opensea](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/5293549666963-Creators-on-Solana-) says:

> Creators can access their collection by connecting with the Solana wallet address of the update authority for your collection. You’ll be able to edit OpenSea-specific items like your logo and collection name, but creator earnings can only be edited on-chain.

and I see you said:

> When I created the CM I used a Solana CLI wallet to hold the update authority and I don't want to import this wallet into a web wallet as I then lose the ability to update the CM via sugar and my CLI wallet.

you won't lose. add your wallet(collection update auth) to the phantom extension and after completing your adjustment remove it.

for adding a new wallet from Solana CLI to phantom extension:

1. open up your new wallet by vs code and copy its content
2. open up your phantom extension and hit add/connect wallet->import private key
3. paste copied wallet to the private key placeholder and also give it a name
4. done

another point to mention is if you look at this page from solscan website, you can see your collection creators are not verified. you can verify them with [metaboss tools](https://metaboss.rs/sign.html?highlight=verify#sign-all) easily.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful. However, when I'm trying to import my Solana CLI wallet to the Phantom extension, I use the 12 word seed phrase but then Phantom shows me a list of pubkeys but I can't find the pubkey from the Solana CLI, e.g. I can't import the update authority pubkey. Any ideas?

Comment: I just updated my answer